# Problems with matrix dimensions for neural network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm training a neural network to predict outputs.
I have a testing set called testX that is a 4x13 matrix, the number of neurons is 10 and the expected output named forecastOutput is a 1x13 matrix. In addition, net.IW{1} is a 10x4 matrix and net.b{1} is a 10x1 matrix.
[image]

Instead of using the sim function, I tried the following code in Matlab to predict the output.

```
y = logsig(net.IW{1} * testX + net.b{1});
forecastOutput = purelin(net.LW{2} * y + net.b{2});
```

However, there is an error on matrix dimensions. How can I obtain the output of 1x13 matrix using the these codes?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the different dimensions. `size(net.IW{1})`, `size(net.b{1})` etc. Please update the question with this information.

Comment: @Robert P I have updated my question with the initial weights and bias dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is with the dimension mismatch in `y = logsig(net.IW{1} * testX + net.b{1});`.

What you are trying to do here is adding a vector (`net.b{1}` and a matrix `net.IW{1}`). Consider the following:

```
A =
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

B =
   1
   2
   3
```

`C = A + B` is not a valid expression, mathematically. If you want to add every column in `A` by `B`, you could do:

```
C = bsxfun(@plus,A,B)   % Or C = A + repmat(B, 1, size(A,2))
C =
    2    3    4
    6    7    8
   10   11   12
```

If you want to add just the kth column of `A` with `B` to receive a vector, you could do:

```
C = A(:,k) + B    % k = 1 gives the following result
C =
    2
    6
   10
```

I guess you have the same problem in the next expression (I assume `size(net.IW{1}) ==  size(net.IW{2})`).

I don't know which one of the approaches that will give you your desired result, but this will solve your error and should get you on the way.